# While installing the CLI using npm install -g @angular/cli getting the error as:

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular6

```
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/guru/.npm/_logs/2018-10-24T16_44_52_889Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac or Linux, use `sudo` when you get the error message `Permission denied`:

```
sudo npm install
```

On Windows just open the command or bash or powershell using Run as administrator.

Comment: SUDO is a command for MAC similar to "Run as administrator", if you are on WINDOWS then just do NPM INSTALL